# Mongoose schema structure

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

For the mongoose section does anyone knows difference between these two codes for defining Schemas?

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userName : String,
    passWord : String
})

const userSchema = {
    userName : String,
    passWord : String
}
```

like using a JSON object directly instead of wrapping them inside the mongosse Schema function as parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The userSchema object returned by mongoose.Schema looks like this.

```
{
  obj: { userName: [Function: String], passWord: [Function: String] },
  paths: {
    userName: SchemaString {
      enumValues: [],
      regExp: null,
      path: 'userName',
      instance: 'String',
      validators: [],
      getters: [],
      setters: [],
      _presplitPath: [Array],
      options: [SchemaStringOptions],
      _index: null,
      [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
    },
    passWord: SchemaString {
      enumValues: [],
      regExp: null,
      path: 'passWord',
      instance: 'String',
      validators: [],
      getters: [],
      setters: [],
      _presplitPath: [Array],
      options: [SchemaStringOptions],
      _index: null,
      [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
    },
    _id: ObjectId {
      path: '_id',
      instance: 'ObjectID',
      validators: [],
      getters: [],
      setters: [Array],
      _presplitPath: [Array],
      options: [SchemaObjectIdOptions],
      _index: null,
      defaultValue: [Function],
      [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
    }
  },
  aliases: {},
  subpaths: {},
  virtuals: {},
  singleNestedPaths: {},
  nested: {},
  inherits: {},
  callQueue: [],
  _indexes: [],
  methods: {},
  methodOptions: {},
  statics: {},
  tree: {
    userName: [Function: String],
    passWord: [Function: String],
    _id: { auto: true, type: 'ObjectId' }
  },
  query: {},
  childSchemas: [],
  plugins: [],
  '$id': 1,
  mapPaths: [],
  s: { hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map(0) {}, _posts: Map(0) {} } },
  _userProvidedOptions: {},
  options: {
    typePojoToMixed: true,
    typeKey: 'type',
    id: true,
    noVirtualId: false,
    _id: true,
    noId: false,
    validateBeforeSave: true,
    read: null,
    shardKey: null,
    autoIndex: null,
    minimize: true,
    discriminatorKey: '__t',
    optimisticConcurrency: false,
    versionKey: '__v',
    capped: false,
    bufferCommands: true,
    strictQuery: false,
    strict: true
  }
}
```

I hope you see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  import mongoose from 'mongoose';
  const { Schema } = mongoose;

  let blogSchema = new Schema({
    title:  String, // String is shorthand for {type: String}
    author: String,
  });
  
  //OR
  let blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:  String, // String is shorthand for {type: String}
    author: String,
  });
```

is the correct way of defining a schema.